# Serious errors were found while mounting disk drive for /

Tags: 14.04, mount

I have a problem after installing 14.04 64bit on my dell laptop. The error message is `serious errors were found while mounting disk drive for /`

Answer (score 0):

Uhmm not sure if this will work, you rather use chkconfig to start apache and varnish, you can setup crontab @reboot with apache before varnish